# Are signs stackable in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Steven's video on the EATS water/boat transport system, I distinctly saw him with a stack of signs. However, I cannot stack signs! Is this a mod, or is something wrong with my version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>Signs **can** be made to stack, but only through inventory editors such as [InvEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?t=15921), which will allow you to stack as many as 99, or an infinite amount (255).</strike>

In SMP, you can just use the `/give` command.

Yes, signs stack, but only up to 16.

Answer (score 1):

Normally signs aren't stackable.

I don't know of any mods that allow you to stack signs, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

In SMP, if you're an OP (i.e. you can use `give`) you can give yourself e.g. 64 signs, which when collected will result in one single sign and a stack of 63 signs (for whatever reason).